# Объект содержащий массив

Tags: php, rest

Вот есть рабочий код

```
$params = array(
    'user'  => $JDE_user,
    'token' => $JDE_token
);

$date_begin = new DateTime($GET['date_begin']);
$date_end = new DateTime($GET['date_end']);
$post_data = array(
    'states'     => ["Delivered"],
    'date_begin' => $date_begin->format("d.m.Y 00:00:00"),
    'date_end'   => $date_end->format("d.m.Y 23:59:59")
);
$cURL = "https://api.jde.ru/vD/orders?".http_build_query($params);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data));
$JDE = curl_exec($ch);
$JDE = json_decode($JDE, true);
curl_close($ch);
```

мне нужно через форму изменять `'states'`
соответственно я получаю из формы массив

```
[status] => Array
        (
            [0] => NewOrderByClient
            [1] => NotDone
            [2] => OnTerminalPickup
            [3] => OnRoad
            [4] => Delivering
            [5] => Delivered
        )
```

и делаю вот так

```
$i=0; $states = "[";
foreach ($GET['status'] as $key => $value){
  if($i > 0){ $states .= ","; }
  $states .= '"'.$value.'"'; $i++; }
$states .= "]";  

$post_data = array(
    'states'     => $states,
    'date_begin' => $date_begin->format("d.m.Y 00:00:00"),
    'date_end'   => $date_end->format("d.m.Y 23:59:59")
);
```

на выходи от api получаю ошибку...
что я делаю не так?
Спасибо!

[ссылка на мануал api](https://api.jde.ru/dev/api/orders/list-orders.html)

Comment: Какую ошибку вы получаете? Не проще ли вместо вашего кода `$states` использовать функцию `implode` ?

Comment: может и проще, если подскажете как!?
[error] => TsmAPIvD.updateOrders: Invalid class typecast

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл такой ответ:

```
$post_data = array(
    'states'     => array_values($_GET['status']),
    'date_begin' => $date_begin->format("d.m.Y 00:00:00"),
    'date_end'   => $date_end->format("d.m.Y 23:59:59")
);
```